# Converting access SQL to SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to convert this Query  from Microsoft access to **SQL Server 2012**.

```
SELECT
IIF(IsNull(Letter), '', CalculationType)  AS [BF NI Calculation Basis]
FROM NICs
```

I converted it to the follwing, But I keep getting the error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1  Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value 'A' to data type int.

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT 
CHOOSE(ISNULL(Letter,0), '', CalculationType) AS [BF NI Calculation Basis]
FROM NICs
```

and

```
SELECT
IIF(Letter = 0, '', CalculationType) AS [BF NI Calculation Basis]
FROM NICs
```

Comment: What is the datatype of CalculationType ??

Comment: @KrishnrajRana it is Int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if Letter is NULL than write:

```
SELECT
IIF(Letter IS NULL, '', CalculationType) AS [BF NI Calculation Basis]
FROM NICs
```

If you want to check Letter for the Value 0

```
SELECT
IIF(Letter ='0', '', CalculationType) AS [BF NI Calculation Basis]
FROM NICs
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this [MSDN link for IIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213574.aspx)

Returns the data type with the highest precedence from the types in **true_value** and **false_value**. it means in your query true_value is ''(string) and false_value is CalculationType(which is int) and that's the reason you get this error.

So your query should like this.

```
SELECT
IIF(Letter = '0', 0, CalculationType) AS [BF NI Calculation Basis]
FROM NICs
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT CASE
        WHEN Letter IS NULL THEN ''
        ELSE CAST(CalculationType AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    END AS [BF NI Calculation Basis]
FROM NICs
```

That's a solution with the column [ BF NI Calculation Basis] as NVARCHAR.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

is it this what you need?

```
SELECT
CASE
WHEN (ISNULL(Letter,0)) = '' THEN CalculationType ELSE ISNULL(Letter,0) 
END AS [BF NI Calculation Basis]
FROM NICs
```

Look at this:

```
create table #NICs
(
    Letter int,
    CalculationType int
)

insert into #NICs values (1,100)
insert into #NICs values (null,200)
insert into #NICs values ('',300)


SELECT
CASE
WHEN (ISNULL(Letter,0)) = '' THEN CalculationType ELSE ISNULL(Letter,0) 
END AS [BF NI Calculation Basis]
FROM #NICs

drop table #NICs
```

edit:

```
SELECT
CASE
WHEN (ISNULL(try_parse(Letter as int),0)) = '' THEN CalculationType ELSE ISNULL(try_parse(Letter as int),0) 
END AS [BF NI Calculation Basis]
FROM #NICs
```

Comment: I still get the same error message 245 when I try this.